# Change value of marker cluster using folium

Tags: python, leaflet, markers, folium

I would like to know if it was possible to change the value displayed in the marker clusters wich, by default, display the number of markers it contains.

I think [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#customising-the-clustered-markers) customization of marker cluster (depicted [here](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-custom.html)) as implemented in leaflet would fit my needs. But I don't know if it is possible to do so with folium.

My goal is to display an average value contained in the children markers of the clusters.